# Некорректная работа цикла С#, поиск суммы ряда

Tags: c#, ряды

Делаю лабу, нужно найти сумму ряда (или как там правильно), всё вроде сделал верно, но студия выбивает ошибку "попытка деления на нуль", что не так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код, и ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double z = 0.0;
        //переменная для факториала
        int f = 1;
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        for(int i = 1;i<=15;i++)
        {
            //цикл вычисления факториала
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
            {
                f = f * j;
            }
            //поиск суммы ряда
            z = z + (i + x) / f;
        }
        textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(z);
    }
```

Comment: пепеполнение же. Какое максимальное значение f в вашем коде? И какое максимальное в int?

Comment: ну и как бы, вы считаете формулу с делением на целых числах - вам точно так надо делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не так, как минимум, в трех моментах.
1. Как уже сказал tym32167, будет переполнение, потому как потолок типа int для вычисления факториала - 12!, а Вам требуется 15!, следовательно надо использовать Int64, для которого потолок - 20!.
2. У Вас в формуле x - с индексом, что как-бы намекает, что это массив.
3. Городить доп.цикл для факториала - не нужно. В данном случае хватит и цикла по i.

Для консоли код выглядит так:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double z = 0f;
        Int64 f = 1;
        double x;
        for(int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
        {
            // Вводим xi c клавиатуры и конвертируем в double
            // Если строковый ввод некорректный, то х=0;               
            Console.Write("Array member #{0} >", i);
            if (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out x)) x = 0;
            // Считаем следующий член факториала, предыдущая часть уже посчитана в более ранние итерации
            f *= i;
            // суммируем
            z += (i + x) / f; // Тип x - double, поэтому все будет вычисляться как double
            // Вывод можно сделать на каждой итерации, а можно и один раз в конце
            Console.WriteLine(z.ToString("E8"));
        }            
        // А это чтобы увидеть результат
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

При x=0 должно получаться число e (2.718281828), в чем Вы и можете убедиться вводя нули на всех итерациях.
Для WinForms, думаю, сами сможете переделать.

Comment: `Console.Write` поддерживает форматирование, нет смысла делать конкатенацию строк.
`Console.Write("Array member #{0} > ", i);`

Comment: Помутнение-с... Исправил.